# Weird display usage bug by Mathematica 12 on Windows 8 - how to fix it?

Tags: front-end, windows, user-interface

Since I've upgraded to Mathematica 12 on Windows 8, this very weird behaviour has started occuring:
[image: my front end]

(Essentially: the notebook area gets shrunk and minified and an unusable black area appears.)

It happens whenever I close the lid of my laptop. I've found no way to reverse it other than restarting Mathematica which is obviously a less than ideal solution.

Any ideas how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Which computer system? I’ve not seen this on a Mac. Are you using it in full screen mode?

Comment: Windows 8, thanks, I've edited the title to indicate that. Nope, no full screen mode, just plain old maximized. But that doesn't seem to matter, it also happens when it's just a non maximized window.